# How do I iterate through children elements of a div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, iteration

I have a div and it has several input elements in it... I'd like to iterate through each of those elements. Ideas?

Answer (score 574, accepted):

Use [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), you can optionally pass a selector to `children`

```
$('#parentid').children('.childclass').each(function () {
    alert(this.value); // "this" is the current element in the loop
});
```

You could also just use the immediate child selector:

```
$('#mydiv > input').each(function () { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: then use $(this) within the closure to access the "current" item in the loop.

Comment: @amarsuperstar: was just in the process of adding that information :-)

Comment: Is there a way to know the value of "n", assuming $(this) is the "n"th child of the parent?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh: the index is passed as the first argument to the callback function for `each()`.  Check the docs, linked in the answer above.

Answer (score 71):

It is also possible to iterate through all elements within a specific context, no mattter how deeply nested they are:

```
$('input', $('#mydiv')).each(function () {
    console.log($(this)); //log every element found to console output
});
```

The second parameter $('#mydiv') which is passed to the jQuery 'input' Selector is the context. In this case the each() clause will iterate through all input elements within the #mydiv container, even if they are not direct children of #mydiv.

Comment: Probably because of nesting this solution worked for me whilst the other one did not. For that reason I would think that this is normally the better solution.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Any way to make json from their values? I need to post all of theme as json.

Comment: Works great! What if I need all input AND select items though?

Comment: You can select multiple elements through a comma separated list: `$('input,select', $('#mydiv'))`

Answer (score 22):

If you need to loop through child elements *recursively*:

```
function recursiveEach($element){
    $element.children().each(function () {
        var $currentElement = $(this);
        // Show element
        console.info($currentElement);
        // Show events handlers of current element
        console.info($currentElement.data('events'));
        // Loop her children
        recursiveEach($currentElement);
    });
}

// Parent div
recursiveEach($("#div"));
```

---

> **NOTE:**
>   In this example I show the events handlers registered with an object.

Answer (score 15):

```
$('#myDiv').children().each( (index, element) => {
    console.log(index);     // children's index
    console.log(element);   // children's element
 });
```

This iterates through all the children and their element with index value can be accessed separately using *element* and *index* respectively.

Answer (score 8):

It can be done this way as well:

```
$('input', '#div').each(function () {
    console.log($(this)); //log every element found to console output
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you need to use  [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), you can use standard for loop

```
var children = $element.children().not(".pb-sortable-placeholder");
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var currentChild = children.eq(i);
    // whatever logic you want
    var oldPosition = currentChild.data("position");
}
```

this way you can have the standard for loop features like `break` and `continue` works by default

also, the `debugging will be easier`

Comment: My experience is that `$.each()` is always slower than a `for` loop, and this is the only answer that uses it.  The key here is to use the `.eq()` to access the actual element within the `children` array and not bracket (`[]`) notation.

Answer (score 1):

children() is a loop in itself.

```
$('.element').children().animate({
'opacity':'0'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It's working with .attr('value'), for elements attributes

```
$("#element div").each(function() {
   $(this).attr('value')
});
```

Comment: this is a 1:1 repeat of the answer from @UmarAsghar which is 4 years older