# maintain sequence of a Ul Li list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `ul` `li` list which has the option to sort and move the elements up and down. My requirement is that once the user sorts the elements in the desired fashion I want to be able to save that sequence in the DB as well.

Is it possible for me to get an array which contains the id the `li` and the index of the position of that `li`.

eg. in this case, when value = 9 , index should be 0,
value = 11, index = 1 etc.

Sample html rendered is:

```
 <ul id="ul_li_SubCategories" style="width:200px;" class="chargeCapturetable margin0">
    <li sequence="1" title="Category 1" class="liEllipsis" value="9"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 1</a></li>
    <li sequence="2" title="Category 3" class="liEllipsis" value="11"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 3</a></li>
    <li sequence="4" title="Category 4" class="liEllipsis" value="12"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 4</a></li>
    <li sequence="5" title="Category 6" class="liEllipsis" value="22"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 6</a></li>
    <li sequence="6" title="Category 5" class="liEllipsis" value="13"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 5</a></li>
    <li sequence="7" title="Category 7" class="liEllipsis" value="55"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 7</a></li>
    <li sequence="99999" title="Category 8" class="liEllipsis" value="62"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 8</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you need? To get each values or to save them in the DB?

Comment: get index corresponding to the value and insert in DB

Comment: @GauravSachdeva check my unedited answer on your previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046590/move-items-in-ul-li-up-and-down

Comment: @GauravSachdeva anyway I posted the answer here, refer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*get an array which contains the id the `li` and the index of the position of that `li`.*

[`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) can be used in conjunction with [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

```
var arr = $('#ul_li_SubCategories li').map(function (elem) {
    return {
        value : $(this).attr('value'),
        index : $(this).index()
    }
}).get();
```

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = $('#ul_li_SubCategories li').map(function(elem) {
    return {
      value: $(this).attr('value'),
      index: $(this).index()
    }
  }).get();
  
  console.log(arr)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul_li_SubCategories" style="width:200px;" class="chargeCapturetable margin0">
  <li sequence="1" title="Category 1" class="liEllipsis" value="9"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 1</a>
  </li>
  <li sequence="2" title="Category 3" class="liEllipsis" value="11"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 3</a>
  </li>
  <li sequence="4" title="Category 4" class="liEllipsis" value="12"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 4</a>
  </li>
  <li sequence="5" title="Category 6" class="liEllipsis" value="22"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 6</a>
  </li>
  <li sequence="6" title="Category 5" class="liEllipsis" value="13"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 5</a>
  </li>
  <li sequence="7" title="Category 7" class="liEllipsis" value="55"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 7</a>
  </li>
  <li sequence="99999" title="Category 8" class="liEllipsis" value="62"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 8</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

[How do I iterate through child elements of a div using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024391/how-do-i-iterate-through-child-elements-of-a-div-using-jquery)

This should point you in the right direction. Simply replace the `div` with the `ul` in question...

Or, writing code for you in jsFiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Why the downvoting? Is this not the exact answer to the question?

Comment: I didnt do any downvoting...  :o

Comment: Haha... not accusing you, but somebody downvoted... Always curious as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var a = [];
$('#ul_li_SubCategories li').each(function(i){
    a.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(a);
```

Output:

```
 [9, 11, 12, 22, 13, 55, 62]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get each value, then you need to build the array and serialise it, finally you can save it with an Ajax call. Here is a [JSFiddle complete](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/rgf8gjob/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var items = [];

    $('#ul_li_SubCategories > li').each(function () {
        items.push({
            value : $(this).attr('value'),
            index : $(this).index()
        });
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "your url to save the items",
        type: "POST",
        data: items,
        success:function(result){
            alert(result);
        },
        error:function(xhr,status,error){
            alert(status);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below answer

```js
    
    $(function(){

$('.glyphicon-arrow-up').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var _parent = _this.closest('ul');
    var _child = $(_parent).find('li');
    var selected= $(this).closest('li').index();
    jQuery($(_parent).children().eq(selected-1)).before(jQuery($(_parent).children().eq(selected)));

    var _child = _this.closest('ul').children();
    var _childLength = _child.length;

    var input = Array();
    $.each(_child, function(key, val){
        input[key] = $(val).data('id');
    })
     // Use below if required to update into database
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data:{
            'inputArray':input,
            'queryString':'updatePrecedence',
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
});

$('.glyphicon-arrow-down').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var _parent = _this.closest('ul');
    var _child = $(_parent).find('li');
    var selected= $(this).closest('li').index();

    jQuery($(_parent).children().eq(selected+1)).after(jQuery($(_parent).children().eq(selected)));
    selected=selected+1;

    var _child = _this.closest('ul').children();
    var _childLength = _child.length;

    var input = Array();
    $.each(_child, function(key, val){
        input[key] = $(val).data('id');
    })

   // Use below if required to update into database
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data:{
            'inputArray':input,
            'queryString':'updatePrecedence',
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success: function(data){
        }
    });

});

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>Sample 1 <span class="glyphicon-arrow-up">Up</span><span class="glyphicon-arrow-down">Down</span></li>
 <li>Sample 2 <span class="glyphicon-arrow-up">Up</span><span class="glyphicon-arrow-down">Down</span></li>
 <li>Sample 3 <span class="glyphicon-arrow-up">Up</span><span class="glyphicon-arrow-down">Down</span></li>
 <li>Sample 4 <span class="glyphicon-arrow-up">Up</span><span class="glyphicon-arrow-down">Down</span></li>
 <li>Sample 5 <span class="glyphicon-arrow-up">Up</span><span class="glyphicon-arrow-down">Down</span></li>
 <li>Sample 6 <span class="glyphicon-arrow-up">Up</span><span class="glyphicon-arrow-down">Down</span></li>
 <li>Sample 7 <span class="glyphicon-arrow-up">Up</span><span class="glyphicon-arrow-down">Down</span></li>
</ul>
```

You will get the index value, after below lines

```
var input = Array();
    $.each(_child, function(key, val){
        input[key] = $(val).data('id');
    })
```

if you print `console.log(input)` you will get array index