# Getting id of child element html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have javascript code like this:

```
<tr id='$stavkaid'>
    <td class='nonEditableData'>$naziv</td>
    <td contenteditable='true' class='editableData' onkeypress='return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13 || event.charCode == 46) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' onblur='if(innerHTML.length <= 0) { innerHTML = 0 }else{ innerHTML = innerHTML, checkInput(parentNode.id)}'>$kolicina</td>
    <td contenteditable='true' class='editableData' onkeypress='return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13 || event.charCode == 46) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' onblur='if(innerHTML.length <= 0) { innerHTML = 0 }else{ innerHTML = innerHTML, checkInput(parentNode.id)}'>$pcbp</td>
    <td contenteditable='true' class='editableData' onkeypress='return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13 || event.charCode == 46) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' onblur='if(innerHTML.length <= 0) { innerHTML = 0 }else{ innerHTML = innerHTML, checkInput(parentNode.id)}'>$rabat</td>
    <td class='nonEditableData'>$pcsp</td>
    <td class='nonEditableData'>$pvsp</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see inside 3 `td` i run javascript function `checkInput(parentNode.id)`

Function looks like this:

```
function checkInput(stavkaID)
{
    alert(stavkaID);
}
```

And it works like charm but now what i want is to somehow get values of each row `tr` where `stavkaID` is selected one.

So how it went in my head is to somehow inside function i do something like this

```
function checkInput(stavkaID)
{
    var naziv = getElementById(stavkaID).nowSomehowIdentifyTDWithValueFor(naziv).innerHTML;
    //And like this for other 5 variables
}
```

I know i can loop through each element of `tr` with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024391/how-do-i-iterate-through-child-elements-of-a-div-using-jquery) but problem is identifying `td` my loop is currently at.

I cannot set id for `td` since it will be static and next time i create `tr` it will have same id which is not possible.

Comment: a `tr` element has a `cells` property, which is a `HTMLCollection` - is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

Use `this`.

```
onkeypress="...; checkInput(parentNode.id, this)"
```

and

```
function checkInput(stavkaId, td) {
   console.log(stavkaId, td);
}
```