# push children of div to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` with some child elements inside it. I'm trying to loop through the `div` and push each child to an object array but I can't figure out how to loop through a `div`.

I have tried

```
$("#id").children('div').each(function(){arrayName.push(this.html)}
```

with no luck. Here is what I have so far.

```
$("#todocontentInner").children('div').each(function() { 
   oldContent.push(this.html());
            });
```

I expect oldcontent to equal something kinda like this

```
["<div class="contentitem">Bob</div>", "<div class="contentitem">Joe</div"]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024391/how-do-i-iterate-through-child-elements-of-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: @mahadevkalyansrikanth The iteration isn't really part of this question. This is about how to push the elements' HTML to an array.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is correct, except that `this` is an element instance. So in order to call the `html()` you need to make this a jQuery instance by `$(this)`. Try the code below.

```js
let arr = [];

$("#parent div").each(function() {
  arr.push($(this).html());
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div>child 1</div>
  <div>child 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain this answer

Answer (score 0):

You dont need jQuery for this:

```js
const arr = [...document.querySelectorAll('#someID > div')].map(el => el.innerHTML);

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div id="someID">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code of

```
$("#id").children('div').each(function(){arrayName.push(this.html)}
```

is almost correct. The problem is that `this.html` is mistaken. You could use `this.innerHTML`, like

```
$("#id").children('div').each(function(){arrayName.push(this.innerHTML)}
```

because `this` in that context represents the element. However, you can do this in the jQuery way as well:

```
$("#id").children('div').each(function(){arrayName.push($(this).html)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear the air: `this` returns a native DOM element, whereas `$(this)` will return its equivalent jQuery element. As `.html()` is a jQuery method, it will only work on the jQuery element, not the native DOM element. So to get the HTML of an element, you will have to use either `this.innerHTML` or `$(this).html()`.

However; it will still not produce the result you expect. To push the full HTML of the child elements, you will need to push their `outerHTML` instead.

TLDR; You will get the expected result by pushing the HTML of the native DOM element using `this.outerHTML`:

```
$("#id").children('div').each(function(){arrayName.push(this.outerHTML)})
```

Or if you really want to use jQuery, you will get the same result from `$(this).prop('outerHTML')`:

```
$("#id").children('div').each(function(){arrayName.push($(this).prop('outerHTML'))})
```

You can see a working sample here:

```js
let arrayName = []
$("#id").children('div').each(function(){arrayName.push(this.outerHTML)})
console.log("First approach: ", arrayName)

let arrayName2 = []
$("#id").children('div').each(function(){arrayName2.push($(this).prop('outerHTML'))})
console.log("Second approach: ", arrayName2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id">
  <div class="contentitem">Bob</div>
  <div class="contentitem">Joe</div>
</div>
```